# selenium webdriver phantomjs url with non-ascii character

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, character-encoding, phantomjs, url-encoding

when i use selenium + phantomjs to crawl a url within non-ascii character,the result page source isn't the page i want to get, i've encode the url before use phantomjs get the url.

```
def phantomTianyanchaSearch(name):
    by = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    url = 'http://www.tianyancha.com/search/' + urllib.quote_plus(name) + '?checkFrom=searchBox'
    by.get(url)
    f = open('logs/phantom_tianyancha'+name+'.html', 'w')
    page = by.page_source.encode('utf-8')
    f.write(page)
    f.close()
    print url, '\tgot', len(page)
    print by.current_url
    by.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   # phantomYaozh()
   # chromeTianyancha('1218773262')
   companyids = ['1218773262', '719792175', '2347856627', '2342953041']
   # phantomTianyanchas(companyids)
   phantomTianyanchaSearch('汕头金石制药总厂')
```

and here is the print result:

```
http://www.tianyancha.com/search/%E6%B1%95%E5%A4%B4%E9%87%91%E7%9F%B3%E5%88%B6%E8%8D%AF%E6%80%BB%E5%8E%82?checkFrom=searchBox   got 51294
http://www.tianyancha.com/?from=i
```

so, the problem is that phantomjs didn't get the correct page, it seems phantomjs can't recognise chinese wored, so it search nothing. how can I fix it?

Comment: This is more likely related to the anti-bot system of that site you're trying to scrape.

Comment: @Artjom B.  but when i use chrome to scrape the same url, the result is right.

Comment: I opened the page in Firefox and Opera and immediately got a captcha request.

Comment: I believe the search keyword would be replaced by ??? on your screenshots. Instead of "by = webdriver.PhantomJS()" use "by = webdriver.Firefox()" or else install chinese font to resolve this problem. Let me know which OS are you using.

Comment: thanks！I use ubuntu14.04, I need to use a headless browser. @Rameez